# getting a NoClassDefFoundError on "PlusImageView"

Tags: android, google-play-services, proguard, google-plus-one

### Background

[**My app**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lb.app_manager) has a small PlusOne button in it (using Google-Play-Services rev. 21.0.2) , and recently I got the next crash report from one of the users

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.os.AsyncTask
at com.google.android.gms.plus.data.internal.PlusImageView.a(SourceFile:60)
at com.google.android.gms.plus.internal.bw.a(SourceFile:917)
at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.v.d(SourceFile:200)
at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.u.handleMessage(SourceFile:136)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3770)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:912)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:670)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

### The problem

I've followed all of the [**instructions of the Play Services**](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html) for a very long time (including the Proguard part), and never had this issue before.

The weird thing is that I've succeeded running the app on multiple devices without any issue, and there are quite a lot of users out there that use my app . Many also uninstall, but this is the first time I get this crash.

### The question

I'm not a Proguard expert, but is it maybe possible that this is the reason for it?

What could be the reason for this issue?

How can I fix this issue?

I've tried to search for this problem and there isn't even a single website that I've found regarding it.